# Create txt-file in Unicode C++

Tags: c++, file, unicode

How create txt-file in Unicode coding using C++ and WinAPI? The file must be in Unicode after creating. I used all methond, but couldn't do something.

Comment: Show us what you did so we have somewhere to start.  The short answer is you write wide text to the file.

Comment: Files are just blobs of bytes. You just write the right bytes to it. You need more questions to get your answer.

Comment: Are you sure you even know what Unicode is?  Based on the wording of the question, I think it's unlikely that you do.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Unicode_Transformation_Format_and_Universal_Character_Set) is a fine start. @RetiredNinja: Why wide text? He hasn't even stated which mapping he wants.

Comment: As hinted by @BenjaminLindley, you need to decide which Unicode *encoding* you want. Your choices are probably UTF-8 and UTF-16, but it depends on who's going to be reading the file.